# ExpressionEngine Entry Date BST Issue

Tags: php, date, expressionengine

Our server timezone is set to UTC, but due to BST, our ExpressionEngine entry dates is 1 hour behind.

Changing daylight savings options in the Localisation settings has no effect, neither does changing the timezone to UTC+1.

This issue causes a 1 hour lag for child content appearing on parent pages, so is a major issue for us.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `date_default_timezone_set` to change the default timezone. See [here](https://www.php.net/date_default_timezone_set) for more details.

In your case, in order to have UTC+1 you can use the following:

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Rome");
```

Answer (score 0):

We were on v2.5.5, I believe this is resolved as part of v2.6 where localization settings were updated and actually work as expected.